# NodeJs Lambda Layers and webpack (without serverless)

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda

I've got a lambda function which is connecting to some layers. It's built using nodejs/typescript and I'm trying to get it built using webpack.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to package the app using webpack with my layer module imports.

For example,  I have a reference like this in my application:

`import { ProductEntity, IProduct, productEntityManager } from "/opt/nodejs/orm";`

If I try to run webpack normally, i'll get a Module not found error saying it can't find "/opt/nodejs/orm".

So I've added in the ignore plugin as below:

```
"use strict";
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ignore = new webpack.IgnorePlugin({resourceRegExp:/^(\/opt\/nodejs\/search|\/opt\/nodejs\/orm|\/opt\/nodejs\/put-event)$/})

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: "./src/handler.ts",
  mode: "production",
  target: "node",
  plugins: [ignore],
  node: {
    __dirname: true,
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ".build"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
        loader: "graphql-tag/loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: [
          [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, ".serverless"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, ".webpack")
          ],
        ],
        options: {
          transpileOnly: false,
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
};
```

And now I get the same error, but it's just baked in to my packaged js file.

I get something like this appear in that bundled js file:

```
...
var e=new Error("Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/orm'")
...
```

So my question is...  How do I build my lambda function using webpack and get it to not try and resolve or import the lambda layer modules?
I can see a lot of examples using serverless but I'm not using it (and not planning to because I'm using terraform).